# How to generate a random matrix and its average value is a specified value

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to generate a random matrix whose average value is a specified value,such as 5.5. I found these function [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixDistributions.html).But I don't know how to use it to do this.I think `MatrixPropertyDistribution` maybe can help a lot.
Since the `NormalDistribution` can assign a mean value,so I give a try like this

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5.5, 1], {3, 3}];
Mean@Mean@list
```

> 6.03623

But as we see,the mean value isn't 5.5 exactly.Could any suggestion give?

Comment: With what distribution of values? That is, one could have values uniformly distributed over some interval with a specified mean, or distributed normally with a specified mean, or...

Comment: @ciao But we cannot  make its average value equal to 5.5 exactly.

Comment: I see you edited in an answer to my comment. You could use something like `With[{wantmean = 5.5}, 
 RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[wantmean, 1], {3, 3}] // #*
    wantmean/Mean[Flatten@#] &]` I suppose.

Comment: @ciao Yes.I need this.But I did not think it would be implemented like this.haha~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 11}, {3, 3}];
list = list + 5.5 - Mean[Mean[list]]
Mean[Mean[list]]
```

> {{8.82553, 10.7335, 4.63438}, {2.8386, 1.73321, 8.4593}, {1.64362, 
>     1.59518, 9.03668}}
>
> 5.5